# Can a human "bless" anything?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, verbs, religion

Does the word "bless" apply only to God? For example, can a human bless anything (such as "bless the day")? Or can only God bless?

Note, I am asking about the usage of the word "bless", and not about religion.

Is there a definition of the word *bless* that describes an accepted usage of the word in a secular way?

Comment: The question is a bit confusing because either you're asking about the/a religious definition of bless and who can provide such (this would be a theological/religious/POV question) or you're asking about any definition of bless and who can provide such, at which point any non-religious definition of bless answers the question.

Comment: Given that Christ fed the five thousand with loaves and fishes, is talking of bread and fish religious? If you are going to abandon anything that has religious origins or implications, a large portion of western culture and language will be out of bounds. For example what will you call the days that you now call 'holidays'?

Comment: You are not asking about the use of the word *bless*, you asking who can bless. Anyone can use the word *bless*, otherwise it wouldn't exist. You have used *bless* in your very question. I do not understand this question.

Comment: @MattЭллен Three other people apparently did understand. Answered and accepted and then closed, who benefits?

Comment: @Frank perhaps you can phrase the question in a way that I can understand then. Anyone can edit. The basis of putting this on hold is so that it can be cleaned up into a workable state. "can a human bless something?" is not a question about usage. If this is a question about meaning, it should be edited as such, not left in a state where is contradicts itself.

Comment: @MattЭллен I have paraphrased the question so it can now probably be closed as General Reference, the OP has his answer so I don't imagine he'll be back in a week to see if there are any better answers.

Comment: @Frank Thank you! I will reopen it and see what the community thinks.

Comment: @MattЭллен Perhaps it would be worth it to add a comment to questions you (and all mods) don't understand asking for someone to edit the question to make it's meaning more clear before mod-closing them, maybe giving an hours deadline or something like that. _It's unclear what you are asking, if the question is not edited to make it clearer within an hour it will be closed_ type comment might encourage clarification and more answers. As far as I know, it's not possible to tell from the 'outside' how close a question is to being closed.

Comment: @Frank It's put on hold so that people do not try and guess what the OP means and post misguided answers, to give the asker time to edit it into shape.

Comment: bless your cotton socks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, "bless" does indeed have a secular meaning, like many words borrowed from theological practices. As a programmer sometimes one program will "bless" a component or another program, so that the system knows going forward the blessed program is special in some way. Perhaps if there are conflicting instructions, only the blessed one should be listened to.

Priests often say "I bless you in the name of the Father..." which I will assert from an English language standpoint means the priest is doing the blessing, not God. For a theological standpoint, please consult your local priest.

The point is, of course it's a fluid word like any in English. And yes, it certainly makes sense for any entity with agency to bless anything else. The listener or reader does not need to be specifically knowledgeable of the secular usage to draw the proper metaphor and understand the blessed thing is now special, by declaration, on the authority of some shared belief in a higher power (whether it's the law, a computer system, or God.)

Answer (score 10):

The OED gives very extensive treatment to the verb 'bless'. I think that its meaning 7 is perhaps relevant to this question. Note that whilst it was 'originally said of God; in later use also of men and things'. In addition to the below the OED also mentions the popular saying about 'having a penny to bless oneself with', referring to a cross on an old silver penny. But I think meaning 7 is interesting. I have significantly edited the vast list of examples:

7.
a. **To confer well-being upon; ‘to make happy; to prosper, make successful’ (Johnson). Originally said of God; in later use also of men and things, but generally with an implication of their conferring instrumentally a divine blessing.** (Here the association of bless with bliss becomes apparent.)

1549   Bk. Common Prayer (STC 16267) Matrimonie f. xvi*,   Looke, O Lord, mercifully vpon them from heauen, and blesse them.
1600   Shakespeare Merchant of Venice iv. i. 183   It [sc. mercy] is twice blest, it blesseth him that giues, and him that takes.
1850   T. T. Lynch Memorials Theophilus Trinal v. 88   To say that good gives pleasure seems poor expression of the truth that it blesses us.

b. To make happy with some gift: orig. of God as the giver; also of persons or things. (In the first example, blitsian may be really = bliðsian (in bliss n.).)

1600   B. Jonson Every Man out of his Humor ii. iii. 70   She was blest with no more Copie of wit.
1606   Returne from Pernassus ii. v. sig. D2,   I will blesse your eares with a very pretty story.
1649   R. Baxter Saints Everlasting Rest (new ed.) iii. i. 266,   I should..return him hearty thanks upon my knees, that ever he blessed his Word in my mouth with such desired success.
1712   J. Arbuthnot John Bull in his Senses iv. 15   Mrs. Bull..bless'd John with three daughters.

**Therefore, in summary it does appear that a human being and an inanimate thing can 'bless' as subject of the verb, though usually with a suggestion, sometimes express sometimes implied, of the blessing being of divine origin**

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a simpler answer for the example that you gave ("bless the day"): in this phrase, "bless" is in the subjunctive mood, i.e. the speaker is expressing their wish that a divine being of some sort should bestow blessings. Admittedly, it's not perfectly clear to me how anyone could "bless" a day, but I take this to be an idiomatic usage along the lines of "bless you", "bless your heart", or "bless its pointed little head".

Answer (score 0):

In the religious sense, to bless is equivalent to magically grant [a] favour to someone - only those, usually gods, shamans, or holy men can do this.

> 1843 "A Christmas Carol" C. Dickens *“God bless us every one!” said Tiny Tim, the last of all.*

> 1855   C. Kingsley Westward Ho! I. ii. 68  *‘Matthew, Mark, Luke, and John, Bless the bed that I lie on.’*

> 2016 Edoardo Albert  "Oswiu: King of Kings" *But my priest tells me Woden has blessed me. Ah, that we might only choose which blessings we receive from the gods.”*

However, recently, my son asked his girlfriend's mother for her blessing to marry her daughter. She gave that blessing. In such cases, the blessing is a statement in favour of something, accompanied by the idea of making someone happy.

This use comes from a confusion of two verbs in Old English:

OED

> **Bless:** Etymology: Old English **blóedsian , blédsian , blétsian**

> At a very early date the popular etymological consciousness began to associate this verb with **bliss v**. ‘benignity, blitheness, joy, happiness,’ which affected the use of both words (see especially senses 7, 8), and led to occasional Middle English spelling of the verb with i, y

> **Bliss** v. Etymology: Old English **blíðsian , blissian**

> **Bliss v. **2. transitive. To give joy or gladness to (originally with dative); to gladden, make happy. (In 16–17th centuries blended with bless.) Obsolete.**

> 1634   C. Fitzgeffry Holy Raptvres ix, in Blessed Birth-day 50   *To thee, who com'st from heauen to blisse the earth.*

and hence:

> III. To declare to be supernaturally favoured; to pronounce or make happy.

> 6. To pronounce words that confer (or are held to confer) supernatural favour and well-being.

This gives the supernaturally favoured effect

and

> **7.a. To confer well-being upon; ‘to make happy; to prosper, make successful’ (Johnson). Originally said of God; in later use also of men and things, but generally with an implication of their conferring instrumentally a divine blessing. (Here the association of bless with bliss becomes apparent.)**

> 1549   Bk. Common Prayer (STC 16267) Matrimonie f. xvi*   *Look, O Lord, mercifully upon them from heaven, and bless them.*

> 1578   Gude & Godlie Ballates (1868) 65   *Bliss, blissit God, the good gift which thou has given to be our food.*

This gives the "make happy" effect.

The end result is that anyone can bless anything.